# How to set width/height for any widget through Theme in Android

Tags: android, themes

I need to use same widgets(buttons,editext,textviews) with same properties like width,height,textColor,size etc in multiple screens (xmls). So I created styles for individual widgets (one style for button, one for edit text ...) and I defined all these styles in my CustomTheme.

My Problem is

If I define layout width/height also in styles and simply giving style="@style/myButtonStyle" for button in xml is working fine even though I did n't mention width/height in xml (might be inheriting from Style).

If I give width/height in xml without style prop and simply giving my Custom theme to activity is bringing all styles I specified in theme. But I did n't mention width/height in xml it is raising an exception saying that u have specify layout width/height, which I already specified in style itself.

my theme file is

```
 <style name="Theme.Blue" parent="android:Theme">
 <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/button222</item>
<item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/text222</item>
<item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/edittext222</item>
</style>
```

and my button222 style is

```
 <style name="button222" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
<item name="android:layout_width">@dimen/mWidth</item>
<item name="android:textColor">#F56266</item>
<item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
```

and I specified dimension as

```
       <dimen name="mWidth">180dip</dimen>
```

and I used like this in layout.xml

```
                          <Button   android:layout_width="180dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="This is large text."
                />

            <Button
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="This is regular text one"
                />

            <Button
                style="@style/button222"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="This is regular text."
                />
```

and it is giving exception saying specify layout width, which I mentioned in button222 style and trying to use through my theme.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should insert a dimension value within the style xml:

```
<dimen name="buttonHeight">40px</dimen>
```

Then you simply should reference the dimension value. So in your layout file you'll write:

```
android:layout_height="@dimen/buttonHeight"
```

Comment: so you still have to write `android:layout_height="@dimen/buttonHeight"` for every button? how does this shorten it?

Answer (score 1):

Just reference the style via app theme and this error will disappear. Do it like so:

```
style="@style/Theme.blue"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your aim is: is it important to you to avoid having to mention `layout_width` and `layout_height` in the layout.xml file, or are you just looking for any way of using the values from the theme without referring to an individual style?

In the latter case, the solution would be

```
layout_width="?attr/myCustomWidth"
```

where in your CustomTheme you have defined an attribute `myCustomWidth`.

Comment: Tx @marc1s. I would like to avoid layout_width and Layout_height in the layout.xml file.

Comment: yes and the reason would be to have all the button, textfields or whatevers definition being in the style definition rather than part of it being there and part in some values file